# Where is the App permission for "identity" in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to use an emulator with which comes with Android Studio, to see what permissions a user can enable / disable from this device.

While a developer can declare he needs access to "Identity" or contact card, it seems that in the emulator, there is no option to display the apps that have disabled access to "identity".

Does this mean that there is no option for a user to refuse access to identity ? Or is it just that it does not appear in the emulator unless you create an app that requests identity ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an API 23 emulator, the grouping of Android permissions has changed for the new [runtime permissions model](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/building-better-apps-with-runtime.html). The full list of dangerous permissions and their associated groups can be found [on this table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permission-groups).

You'll note that most of the permissions in the old Identity bucket have either been removed entirely or moved to the 'Contacts' group (as is the case for [GET_ACCOUNTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS)).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "removed" ? Does it mean an app can no longer determine a users identity ? (I don't mean accounts - I mean specifically first name, and last name, from contact cards).

Answer (score 3):

Only "dangerous" permissions need to be requested from user in Android 6.0. Others are granted automatically when they are declared in the manifest.

List of dangerous permissions can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous - they are divided in groups, which are:

> CALENDAR
>
> ```
> READ_CALENDAR
>
> WRITE_CALENDAR
> ```
>
> CAMERA
>
> ```
> CAMERA
> ```
>
> CONTACTS
>
> ```
> READ_CONTACTS
> WRITE_CONTACTS
> GET_ACCOUNTS
> ```
>
> LOCATION
>
> ```
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> ```
>
> MICROPHONE
>
> ```
> RECORD_AUDIO
> ```
>
> PHONE
>
> ```
> READ_PHONE_STATE
> CALL_PHONE
> READ_CALL_LOG
> WRITE_CALL_LOG
> ADD_VOICEMAIL
> USE_SIP
> PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
> ```
>
> SENSORS
>
> ```
> BODY_SENSORS
> ```
>
> SMS
>
> ```
> SEND_SMS
> RECEIVE_SMS
> READ_SMS
> RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
> RECEIVE_MMS
> ```
>
> STORAGE
>
> ```
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> ```

Comment: +1 How the permission will get invoked to the user if the permission is get invoked in background service. Ex: Read call log function is written in service.

Comment: So where is the "identity" permission ? "Read contact card" etc ? Has that been removed ? Does that mean apps can no longer determine someones identity ? Note that identity is different from accounts, because Identity is like my first and last name, but I can have many accounts (friends / relatives sharing my device)