# How to ask for Identity permission in android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Please let me know what is identity permissions? And how to implement from code this kind of permission?

II have already implement contacts read and other runtime permission but unable to find anything about identity permission.

Comment: possible duplicate question pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295810/where-is-the-app-permission-for-identity-in-android-marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

GET_ACCOUNTS was previously in the Identity permission group.

It moved to the Contacts permission group in Android 6.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS

[Android 6.0 permission.GET_ACCOUNTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124930/android-6-0-permission-get-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Identity – With this permission the app can find accounts on the device, see and modify the owner’s contact card and add or remove contacts from the device. The permission **group CONTACTS deals with the user’s contacts while ACCOUNT_MANAGER deals with the user’s accounts.**

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>

At code level one can set permission by using **https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html**
First check
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.group.CONTACTS);
```

Comment: i have tried this but getting error as Error:(11) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character '-'. 
beacuse of this:- android.permission-group

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.group.CONTACTS"/> may resolve your issue